# Hava alias shortcut available in new terminal session

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

The output of  command `$ alias`  will not display for me  in Ubuntu 18.04.
as I research [here](https://www.routerhosting.com/knowledge-base/what-is-linux-bashrc-and-how-to-use-it-full-guide/) This is only available for my current terminal session, and if I open a new terminal session, the Alias will no longer be available. So, I require a permanent Alias.
can anyone suggest any other soloution?

Answer (score 2):

To have your alias definitions available anytime, define them in your `.bashrc` file. It is a hidden file in your home directory, and is executed automatically each time you open a terminal.

Open that file with your text editor. A good place to add your own aliases is where some aliases are already defined. You will find a comment line: `# some more ls aliases`. There, you can add your own aliases. Save and close the file when done. From now on, your new aliases will be available in any new terminal.

If you maintain a lot of aliases, it is more practical to create a separate file with the name `~/.bash_aliases` and put all your alias definitions there. Ubuntu is set up to automatically source an existing `.bash_aliases` file in `.bashrc`.